# ffmpeg command not working from bash script but working from command line

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

I wrote a `bash` script that is generating command to encode video and create HLS playlist.

Here is the script. To make it short and clear, i fill variables with hard-coded values.

```
#!/bin/bash

# below variables are generated from some other script

basic="-hide_banner -y -i Sample.mp4 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 50 -keyint_min 50 -hls_time 6"

renditions="-c:v:0 h264 -filter:v:0 scale=w=426:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -b:v:0 128k -maxrate:v:0 136k -bufsize:v:0 192k -c:v:1 h264 -filter:v:1 scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -b:v:1 256k -maxrate:v:1 273k -bufsize:v:1 384k -b:a 128k -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2"

mapping="-map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a"
stream_map="-var_stream_map \"v:0,agroup:audio v:1,agroup:audio a:0,agroup:audio\""

hls="-hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type mpegts -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -y %v_seg.m3u8"

# show final command
echo "Command:"
echo "ffmpeg ${basic} ${renditions} ${mapping} ${stream_map} ${hls}"

# execute command
ffmpeg ${basic} ${renditions} ${mapping} ${stream_map} ${hls}
```

Here is complete output from the script, along with the error it is giving.

```
[samtech@SAM tmp]$ ./hls-debug.sh 
Command:
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i Sample.mp4 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 50 -keyint_min 50 -hls_time 10 -c:v:0 h264 -filter:v:0 scale=w=426:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -b:v:0 128k -maxrate:v:0 136k -bufsize:v:0 192k -c:v:1 h264 -filter:v:1 scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -b:v:1 256k -maxrate:v:1 273k -bufsize:v:1 384k -b:a 128k -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a -var_stream_map "v:0,agroup:audio v:1,agroup:audio a:0,agroup:audio" -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type mpegts -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -y %v_seg.m3u8
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x562fabc34480] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 640x480, 997 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:31.00, start: 0.002000, bitrate: 1146 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 640x480, 997 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[NULL @ 0x562fabc69680] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'v:1,agroup:audio'
v:1,agroup:audio: Invalid argument
```

And here is output when i copy command and run in terminal

```
[samtech@SAM tmp]$ ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i Sample.mp4 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 50 -keyint_min 50 -hls_time 10 -c:v:0 h264 -filter:v:0 scale=w=426:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -b:v:0 128k -maxrate:v:0 136k -bufsize:v:0 192k -c:v:1 h264 -filter:v:1 scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -b:v:1 256k -maxrate:v:1 273k -bufsize:v:1 384k -b:a 128k -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a -var_stream_map "v:0,agroup:audio v:1,agroup:audio a:0,agroup:audio" -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type mpegts -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -y %v_seg.m3u8
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55eeed0c7500] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 640x480, 997 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:31.00, start: 0.002000, bitrate: 1146 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 640x480, 997 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] profile Main, level 1.3, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=7 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=50 keyint_min=26 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=136 vbv_bufsize=192 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] profile Main, level 2.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=11 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=50 keyint_min=26 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=273 vbv_bufsize=384 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mpegts @ 0x55eef094a180] frame size not set
Output #0, hls, to '%v_seg.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 136000/0/128000 buffer size: 192000 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 256 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 273000/0/256000 buffer size: 384000 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 aac
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '0_seg0.ts' for writing10.98 bitrate=N/A dup=370 drop=0 speed=11.2x    
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '1_seg0.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '2_seg0.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '0_seg1.ts' for writing17.53 bitrate=N/A dup=370 drop=0 speed=11.8x    
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '1_seg1.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '2_seg1.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '0_seg2.ts' for writing28.75 bitrate=N/A dup=370 drop=0 speed=11.6x    
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '1_seg2.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '2_seg2.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '0_seg3.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '0_seg.m3u8' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '1_seg3.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '1_seg.m3u8' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '2_seg3.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening '2_seg.m3u8' for writing
[hls @ 0x55eeed0fc700] Opening 'master.m3u8' for writing
frame=  775 fps=264 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:30.97 bitrate=N/A dup=370 drop=0 speed=10.6x    
video:1227kB audio:489kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] frame I:16    Avg QP:17.53  size:  9672
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] frame P:328   Avg QP:20.42  size:   690
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] frame B:431   Avg QP:18.51  size:   125
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] consecutive B-frames: 20.6% 13.2%  7.4% 58.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] mb I  I16..4: 33.1%  0.0% 66.9%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.8%  0.0%  2.4%  P16..4: 15.3%  7.5%  4.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:69.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 10.8%  1.7%  0.4%  direct: 0.4%  skip:86.6%  L0:40.4% L1:51.0% BI: 8.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 70.8% 80.4% 61.6% inter: 3.8% 4.7% 0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 17% 39% 23% 21%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 26% 18%  7%  7%  6%  7%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 31% 14% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] ref P L0: 73.7% 16.3%  7.4%  2.6%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] ref B L0: 94.3%  4.9%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] ref B L1: 98.3%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed0ff5c0] kb/s:112.27
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] frame I:16    Avg QP:15.14  size: 18394
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] frame P:260   Avg QP:19.00  size:  1507
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] frame B:499   Avg QP:18.80  size:   269
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] consecutive B-frames:  9.7% 11.4%  6.2% 72.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] mb I  I16..4: 36.5%  0.0% 63.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] mb P  I16..4:  1.2%  0.0%  3.1%  P16..4: 15.5%  7.1%  3.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:69.9%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.1%  B16..8: 11.4%  1.6%  0.3%  direct: 0.4%  skip:86.2%  L0:39.1% L1:53.5% BI: 7.4%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 65.1% 75.8% 54.1% inter: 3.1% 4.5% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 35% 27% 12% 26%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 25% 15%  7%  8%  7%  8%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 29% 14% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] ref P L0: 71.6% 15.9%  8.6%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] ref B L0: 93.9%  4.6%  1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] ref B L1: 98.3%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55eeed106f40] kb/s:211.68
[aac @ 0x55eeed1009c0] Qavg: 401.380
```

What the wrong is going with that script ?

I am pulling my hairs from last few hours because of it, anyone help please.

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes before expanding variables, so putting quotes and/or escapes (and most other shell syntax) in variables doesn't work -- by the time they're part of the command, it's too late for them to do anything useful. See ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948) and [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: You would have the _exact_ same problem if you typed the same content on the command line. It's not about whether it's a script; it's about `cmd='something "with quotes and spaces"'; $cmd` being different from `something "with quotes and spaces"`, for all the reasons given in the links Gordon provided above. (Very, _very_ short summary: Quotes _in your code_ are syntax, quotes _in your variable contents_ are data; only syntax changes how things are parsed -- data doesn't, for very good reasons: If it were otherwise, it would be impossible for shell scripts to handle untrusted data safely).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code (including the problem of quotes in variables not being useful).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save arguments in arrays and then let the array contents expand inside double quotes rather than save the arguments in scalars and then use those scalars unquoted.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# below variables are generated from some other script

basic=( -hide_banner -y -i Sample.mp4 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 50 -keyint_min 50 -hls_time 6 )

renditions=( -c:v:0 h264 -filter:v:0 scale=w=426:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -b:v:0 128k -maxrate:v:0 136k -bufsize:v:0 192k -c:v:1 h264 -filter:v:1 scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -b:v:1 256k -maxrate:v:1 273k -bufsize:v:1 384k -b:a 128k -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 )

mapping=( -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a )
stream_map=( -var_stream_map 'v:0,agroup:audio v:1,agroup:audio a:0,agroup:audio' )

hls=( -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_type mpegts -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -y %v_seg.m3u8 )

# show final command
echo "Command:"
echo ffmpeg "${basic[@]}" "${renditions[@]}" "${mapping[@]}" "${stream_map[@]}" "${hls[@]}"

# execute command
ffmpeg "${basic[@]}" "${renditions[@]}" "${mapping[@]}" "${stream_map[@]}" "${hls[@]}"
```

Comment: i tried the updated script, but now it is giving different error `[hls @ 0x5587c5ea1700] Invalid keyval "v:0
[hls @ 0x5587c5ea1700] Variant stream info update failed with status ffffffea
[out#0/hls @ 0x5587c5e72240] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
[vost#0:1/libx264 @ 0x5587c5eabc40] Error initializing output stream: `

Comment: however still if i copy command to terminal, it works

Comment: I think you want `stream_map=( -var_stream_map "v:0,agroup:audio v:1,agroup:audio a:0,agroup:audio" )` (or the version with only single-quotes, which is equivalent). The general rule is that when setting the array entries, you quote things exactly the same way you would when running the command directly.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've updated it now, thanks. I should've looked at how the OP was running the command on his command line to get that clue.

Comment: @EdMorton updated version of script is working well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i modified original script to use arrays instead of string concatenation, that's is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

As Ed Morton pointed out, you should use an array to pass the arguments.  The way you are trying to pass `stream_map` is problematic.  That's not how quoting works in the shell.  Consider:

```
$ cat show-args
#!/bin/sh

show_args() { for x; do echo arg: "$x"; done; }

show_args a "quoted argument"

arg1=a
arg2="\"quoted argument\""
show_args $arg1 $arg2
$ ./show-args
arg: a
arg: quoted argument
arg: a
arg: "quoted
arg: argument"
```

As demonstrated, the second call to the function `show_args` is very different than the first.  In the first, the shell strips the quotes and passes 2 arguments to the function: the strings `a` and `quoted argument`.  In the second call, the shell passes 3 arguments to the function: the strings `a`, `"quoted`, and `argument"`.  The way you are trying to pass `stream_map` is essentially what is happening in this toy with the second call to `show_args`.